# PHP looping through DIV by ID

Tags: php, jquery, loops, element

I thought I could loop through all divs with the same class using :

```
$("#section").each(function(i){
    alert ($(this).text());
});
```

However when I run this I only get an alert for the first div.

Can someone advise what I'm doing wrong ?

I've created a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qzcxtcr2/) showing the issue.

Thanks

Comment: id should be unique. USe class instead of it

Comment: see the updated fiddle of yours http://jsfiddle.net/qzcxtcr2/1/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi - if you submit as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: Done. Posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have multiple elements with same id in the dom. In such situations, you should use class instead of id.

```
$(".section").each(function(i){
        alert ($(this).text());
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qzcxtcr2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

ID's are limited to one.. They have to be unique.

You will need to change the ID to a class and iterate again.

Comment: Remove `supposed`, IDs should be unique else HTML becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0):

First I will suggest don't use same ID for each Div. If it is then use as below:

```
$("div[id='section']").each(function(i){
    alert ($(this).text());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qzcxtcr2/2/)

I will suggest use ass some post fix in Div ID. use as

```
$("div[id$='section']").each(function(i){
    alert ($(this).text());
});
```

Or Use section as class name as below Demo

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qzcxtcr2/6/)

Answer (score 0):

`#` is ID selector in jQuery. To use class selector you have to use `.`.

Try like this:

```
$(".section").each(function(i){
    alert ($(this).text());
});
```

**NOTE:** `section` is your common class name.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Without Changing Ur Id Or Class

$("#container ul li").each(function(i){

```
alert ($(this).text());
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="aid" style="width:600px; margin: 50px auto 0">

<div id="container" >
<ul id="list">

<li>
    <div class="section" >
    <a href='#' id='show' class='tooltip'>1</a>
<div class='slide' style='display:block; display:none;'>

</div></div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class='section'>
<a href="#" id="show" class='tooltip'>2</a>
<div class="slide" style="display:block; display:none;">

</div></div>
</li>


<li><a href="faq.php" class="tooltip" id='other'>3</a></li>

<li>
    <div class='section'>
<a href="#" id="show" class='tooltip'>4</a>
<div class="slide" style="display:block; display:none;">

</div></div>
</li>


<li>
    <div class='section'>
<a href="#" id="show" class='tooltip'>5</a>
<div class="slide" style="display:block; display:none;">

</div></div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class='section'>
<a href="#" id="show" class='tooltip'>6</a>
<div class="slide" style="display:block; display:none;">
</div></div>
</li>

</ul>
    </div>
    </div>
$(".section").each(function(i){
        alert ($(this).text());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is,you use Id attribute for div.In dom element Id should be unique that's why it is giving alert for first div.Change it to class and then also change in your code.

```
$(".section").each(function(i){
   alert ($(this).text());
});
```